# Azure IOT Apache Avro format

Tags: azure, iot, avro

Using Azure IOT, I have my device endpoint pointing to Azure Blob storage.  Data is sent to the Blob, but i get non-ascii characters and am told that the file extension is incorrect.  Sample Blob data is

`Objavro.codecnullavro.schemaÐ{"type":"record","name":"Message","namespace":"Microsoft.Azure.Devices","fields":[{"name":"EnqueuedTimeUtc","type":"string"},{"name":"Properties","type":{"type":"map","values":"string"}},{"name":"SystemProperties","type":{"type":"map","values":"string"}},{"name":"Body","type":["null","bytes"]}]} ±¡RëZË8è€‘,¡…$•
à82018-02-20T15:12:16.1060000Z $connectionDeviceIdLane4Free(connectionAuthMethodœ{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}8connectionDeviceGenerationId$636543931333384343enqueuedTime82018-02-20T15:12:16.1060000Z d{"deviceId": "myPythonDevice","PinsCCC": 302.00,\}82018-02-20T15:12:16.2000000Z`

Azure IOT docs says that the format is Apache Avro, but I can't find anything on how to decode the  non-ascii characters.  I don't see where to specify a json extension.

Comment: How do you send your data?

Comment: Here's the Python  code that I use. -- message = IoTHubMessage((msg_txt_formatted)) ---
message.ContentEncoding = "utf-8";  ---
message.ContentType = "application/json" ---; 
client.send_event_async(message, send_confirmation_callback, message_counter)

Comment: Reformatted -Here's the Python  code using MQTT.  `message =IoTHubMessage((msg_txt_formatted)) `
`message.ContentEncoding = "utf-8"; `
`message.ContentType = "application/json" ;` 
`client.send_event_async(message, send_confirmation_callback, message_counter)``

Answer (score 1):

It seems [by designed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview).

You can utilize Avro tool to read or convert to JSON format.

Here is a [Python sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-python) to read Avro file.

Comment: I created the sample capturereader.py using avro-python3.  Code finds my blob location **Downloaded a non empty blob: DuckpinFree/01/2018/02/20/17/03** but fails when reading blob in `raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)` with error _json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes_ at line 1 col 46.  The data above puts col 46 well within the double quoted json.??

Comment: I believe that i see the problem.  Line 2 of my data above(first line is header data) contains a non-json pair at about col 46.  IOTHub passes it to blob storage, but since it's not json, I can't read it with the Python Event Hub reader.

Comment: @CliffordEby Can you read valid JSON messages after corrected your code?

Comment: The sample capturereader.py code as written does download and remove all data from Blob storage.  Data are written to individual files in your local client directory.  Non-ascii characters are still present at Xs and other locations in the data - `ObjXXXavro.codecXnullXavro.schemaÐX`   I don't see anything in the avro spec about non-ascii and wonder what puts them there and why?

Comment: Storage Explorer provides a GUI interface and selective download capabilities.  What is the recommended tool for analyzing IOT data stored in Blob storage?

Comment: Since my goal is to analyze the data, I connected the Blob account to PowerBI.  Data downloads to PowerBI, but parsing is a nightmare.  Can you point me to a Blob to PowerBI guide?

Comment: As a workaround, you can add another azure service: Stream Analytics. From stream analytics write data to the storage table and then analyze with PowerBI. [There is a sample](https://www.hackster.io/peejster/processing-iot-device-data-with-azure-and-power-bi-c00e35) you can reference.

Comment: [There is feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-store-data-in-azure-table-storage#next-steps) about your AVRO issue and it is assigned and will be updated. You can vote up it.

Comment: I don't need the functionality of Stream Analytics i.e input = output and I'm trying to minimize costs.  Any samples using functions?   I upvoted the AVRO issue - thx for directing me there.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT - is there a C# sample?  And/or a way to convert the avro to json via an Azure streaming analytics function?

Answer (score 0):

From you original question, seems you need to read the content from ARVO file. Following are the steps to use C# to do that from Azure storage:

1. Install Microsoft.Avro.Core nugget packege

[image]

2. Add following namespaces:

   ```
   using Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro;
   using Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.Container;
   ```
3. Get AVRO records

   ```
   private async Task<List<AvroRecord>> GetAvroRecordsAsync(CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob)
   {
       var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
       await cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
       memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       List<AvroRecord> avroRecords;
       using (var reader = AvroContainer.CreateGenericReader(memoryStream))
       {
           using (var sequentialReader = new SequentialReader<object>(reader))
           {
                 avroRecords = sequentialReader.Objects.OfType<AvroRecord>().ToList();
           }
       }

       return avroRecords;
   }
   ```
4. Deserialize the object from avro record:

   ```
   private MyObject GetMyObject(AvroRecord avroRecord)
   {
       var body = avroRecord.GetField<byte[]>("Body");
       var dataBody= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
       var myObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(dataBody);
       return myObj;
   }
   ```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: The Python Sample above gives me the ability to read and desalinize the AVRO format.This may be what @Stinky Towel is looking for.  <br> I haven't found anything that explains the non-ascii characters inserted by Azure IOT. Also, I was hoping that a json object in Blob strorage would be fully supported by PowerBi that simplifies data downloads from Blob storage.  At present, it's very clumsy.   Thx for the response